# How to get selected value from Kendo-multiSelect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

How to get selected value from Kendo-multiSelect ?

```
$("#doc").kendoMultiSelect({
             value: ,
             dataSource: {
                  data: self.list()
              },

            });
```

Comment: `value: ,` ?? This will throw an exception.

Comment: should be 'value: kovariable '

Comment: i don't write a variable of knockout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
var multiSelectedValues = $("#doc").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
```

which will give result as ["1", "2","so on"]

Answer (score 0):

The code below will get the values of the kendoMultiSelect.

```
var doc= $("#doc").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
```